# sharepoint 2013 library calculated column

Tags: calculated-column, calculated-column-formula, sharepoint-library

I want to create calculated column in SharePoint library, but get error
[image]

**here is error that I got**

[image]

**and also here is column**

[image]

**Can someone tell me what I have done by mistake?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**LEFT function**:

LEFT returns the first character or characters in a text string, based on the number of characters you specify.

> **Syntax**:
>
> **LEFT(text,num_chars)**

**Note**:

Sometimes comma(,) does not work in formula (I am not sure but it is based on something language on your site). So in that case use semicolon(;) instead of comma(,).

**Reference**:

1. [LEFT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/left-function-913824b4-fc42-4c8c-9229-0eaa57dcdf49).

Comment: Thank you that was the problem, I used semicolon and it worked